# How to get NetworkCapabilities object on Android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How to get `android.net.NetworkCapabilities` on Android?

I looked at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html and did not find any way to get `NetworkCapabilities` object.

Any suggestions on how to get it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkCapabilities(android.net.Network) ?

Comment: And what will be the value of network to be passed here?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getProcessDefaultNetwork() won't cut it since it has to be set explicitly.

Answer (score 13):

```
ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Network[] networks = connectivity.getAllNetworks();
    for (int i = 0; i < networks.length; i++) {
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivity.getNetworkCapabilities(networks[i]);    
    }
```

But this is available with API 21 and above.

Comment: Thanks Satty, I figured out the same but is there a way to know the active network here?

Comment: connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo() is deprecated as of 29

Answer (score 5):

```
    NetworkCapabilities nc = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netInfo != null) {
            nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
        }

    }else{

        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        Network[] networks = connectivity.getAllNetworks();
        for (int i = 0; i < networks.length && nc == null; i++) {
            nc = connectivity.getNetworkCapabilities(networks[i]);
        }
    }
    // use now nc
```

On Android > 23 you can use `ConnectivityManager` and `getActiveNetwork()`

Comment: getAllNetworks() and getNetworkCapabilities() is for API >= 21, so your "else" statment doesnt work if API is <21

Comment: Reverse query `if`